# ListView of Dictionary<string,string> Need to extract key value pair as seperate values

Tags: c#, listview, dictionary

So I have a Dictionarr and have bound this to a ListView...

```
        this.dbMessages = new Dictionary<string,string>( dbMessages );
        this.dbPathStr = @"C:\DATABASEROOT\" + databaseName;
        this.dbNameStr = databaseName.Remove(databaseName.LastIndexOf("."));

        dbName.Text = dbNameStr;
        dbPort.Text = "0000";
        msgList.ItemsSource = dbMessages;
        msgList.DisplayMemberPath = "Key";
        msgList.SelectedValuePath = "Value";
```

now this brings me down to selecting values, As a user selects a value and hits the add button I need to extract the Key and Value along with other info on the form to build a custom class object.

The problem is the Key....

```
classObject(string key, string value, string otherinfo) //this is the constructor
```

I have tried accessing the key by just selectedItem.tostring which gives me the pair and i realy do not want to get into string manip.

I have tried casting it back to a dictionary of  but aparently once cast it cannot cast back to a generic dictionary....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `SelectedItem` gives you the pair, just cast it and access the key e.g.

```
var pair = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)msgList.SelectedItem;
var obj = new classObject(pair.Key, pair.Value, otherInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks, I never would have thought about casting it to a generic KeyValuePair, I thought to be as explicit as possible to protect data... so sending it in as a dictionary<T,T> figured I would have to pull it out as the same.